# FROM statement makes my query returns an empty list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a quite long query that is like

```
SELECT A.* FROM A, B, C, D, E 
WHERE A.attr1 LIKE "%hello%"
OR A.attr2 LIKE "%hello%"
OR (statement_that_uses_B_table)
OR (statement_that_uses_C_table)
```

Normally the first statement is matched (A.attr1 = "hello"), but the others not so I have a query like " ... WHERE 1 OR 0 OR 0 OR 0 OR 0". But my query doesn't return anything at all.
The strange thing is that if I delete all the "OR" that uses other tables like

```
SELECT A.* FROM A
WHERE A.attr1 LIKE "%hello%"
OR A.attr2 LIKE "%hello%"
```

It works fine.
And even more weird,

```
SELECT A.* FROM A, B, C, D, E 
WHERE A.attr1 LIKE "%hello%"
OR A.attr2 LIKE "%hello%"
```

Doest not work.
Any idea ?

Comment: Do you intentionally WANT a bulk-join? Depending on how many rows are in your database, this join could fill your memory. Is there any type of join you could explicitly use?

Comment: Show your sample dataset

Comment: You need wildcards for LIKE without them you might as well use `=`.And learn about JOINs

Comment: I use wildcards, I forgot to write them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way that a cartesian join like that will return nothing is if one of the tables are empty, so B,C,D, or E must not have any rows.

```
mysql> select * from t;
+----+------+
| id | data |
+----+------+
|  5 |  778 |
|  1 |  122 |
|  3 |  277 |
|  2 |   20 |
|  4 | 3661 |
+----+------+

mysql> select * from d;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t,d;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into d set id = 5;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from t,d;
+----+------+------+
| id | data | id   |
+----+------+------+
|  5 |  778 |    5 |
|  1 |  122 |    5 |
|  3 |  277 |    5 |
|  2 |   20 |    5 |
|  4 | 3661 |    5 |
+----+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

a `LEFT JOIN` will join data even without a matching term.  Consider:

```
 select * from t left join d on 1;
+----+------+------+
| id | data | id   |
+----+------+------+
|  5 |  778 | NULL |
|  1 |  122 | NULL |
|  3 |  277 | NULL |
|  2 |   20 | NULL |
|  4 | 3661 | NULL |
+----+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: You're right, I have some empty tables.
How can I change this behavior without intentionally filling tables ?

Comment: Added example of a left join with a fake ON clause ( but really it would be better to use a _real_ relational ON clause )